# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire error on device iOS 9 , not able to compile

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, ios9, xcode7.2

I am using "Google analytics " SDK for iOS. The sdk forced me to set `Enable bitcode` from `Yes` to `NO`

When I disabled bitcode I was getting compiling error on my device (iOS 9) buut not on simulator `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/940F4D49-6239-4645-9FAE-99D482BFA1C4/Skip It.app/Skip It
  Reason: image not found`

I added Alamofire via cocoaPods. TO resolve aforementioned error I added Alamofire framework in "Linked Framworks and Libraries" and made It optional, as shown in screenshot[image]

Now I am able to run app on my device (iOS 9), but whenever code which uses Alamofire of other frameworks which are made optional, app get crashed.

I am not able to find solution. I googled a lot but no use. Please someone help

Comment: You have provided more details of the issue you have already solved than the issue you are currently stuck with.  I don't see how anyone can help with "app get crashed".

Answer (score 0):

Same problem - app ran fine in simulator, but crashed on device with the same error.

In my case, it was a missing [Apple WWDR Intermediate Certificate](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/) that caused the problem. The dev certificate couldn't be validated, so the provisioning profile was rejected and the device threw this error.

I downloaded and installed Apple's WWDR Intermediate Certificate, and the error went away.

So check and make sure that your keychain has all the necessary certificates and nothing is missing or expired.